# How to calculate relative value of column depending upon other rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today While working I got a situation similar to this .
Lets assume there is table tblActor. We need to update the relative score of actor which is sum of individual score of same and other actors:

1. If any other actors belongs to different city of current actor then individual score of other actors will be zero.
2. If any other actors belongs to same city and its individual score is less than or equal to a current actor  then Individual score of other actors will be zero.
3. If any other actors belongs to same city and its Individual score is greater than current actor  then Individual score of other actors will be
   ( Other Actor Individual Score - Current Actor Individual Score).
4. Score of same actor will be the Individual score of an actor.

   ```
       Aid    City    IndividualScore       Relative Score
        1      X             1              (1 + (2-1) + (3 -1) + 0 + 0 + 0)
        2      X             2              (0 + 2 + (3 -2) + 0 + 0 + 0)
        3      X             3              (0 + 0 + 3 + 0 + 0 + 0)
        4      Y             2              (0 + 0 + 0 + 2 + 0 + (3-2))
        5      Y             0              (0 + 0 + 0 + 2 + 0 + (3-0))
        6      Y             3              (0 + 0 + 0 + 2 + 0 + 3))
   ```

So how to calculate this relative column kind of field. I am new to sql stuffs.
Please help.

Comment: trying to understand your code, are you sure the relative score is correct ? I would think the last row should be 3 like in @GunnarKnudsen's answer

Comment: The rule 1 seems to indicate that the score are regional -> the same actor should have different score in different region/city as it changes the other actor score, in general the rule for a sql query should be in the form if something then current, not if current then other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select 
  a.AID
, a.City
, a.IndividualScore
, a.IndividualScore
  + sum(case when oa.IndividualScore > a.IndividualScore then oa.IndividualScore - a.IndividualScore else 0 end) as RelativeScore
from tblActor a
left join tblActoroa on a.City = oa.City-- other actor
where a.AID != oa.AID
group by   
  a.AID
, a.City
, a.IndividualScore
```

This query uses almost the same principle as Gordon, and shows (almost) the same results as you posted in OP.

I however don't understand why the RelativeScore = 5, where AID = 6; According to your rules (as i've understood them), it should return 3, since the IndividualScore of AID = 4 is less than then IndividualScore of AID = 6.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is essentially:  "Sum the difference in scores between a given actor and all other actors in the same city, where the other actors have a higher score".  Alas, you cannot quite do this within window functions, but you can with a self join:

```
select t.aid, t.city, t.IndividualScore,
       (t.IndividualScore + sum(t2.IndividualScore - t.IndividualScore)) as RelativeScore
from table t left outer join
     table t2
     on t.city = t2.city and t.aid <> t2.aid and t.IndividualScore < t2.IndividualScore
group by t.aid, t.city, t.IndividualScore;
```